# split string by regex in cpp --special case

Tags: c++, regex, boost, split

I want to split this expression

```
A+ + B
```

by the "+" in between so that I have 
A+ and B at the end

Note that the + after A is apart of the first token and I don't want to split it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string expression="A+ + B"; 
    vector <string> resultArray;
    boost::algorithm::split_regex( resultArray, expression,  boost::regex( " + " ));
    for (int i=0; i<resultArray.size();i++){
    cout <<resultArray[i]<< endl ;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes the plus with space before and after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is a regex character and you have to escape it. Not sure how it do in c++ but usually in other languages its done using a backslash(\) like this `\+` and, for the space, you can use `\s`

So assume this will be your splitting regex:

```
\\s+\\+\\s+
```

It means: any number of spaces, then a plus, then any number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` needs to be escaped with `\`, and furthermore the `\` itself needs to be escaped with `\` again because this is C++.  So:

```
int main()
{
    string expression="A+ + B"; 
    vector <string> resultArray;
    boost::regex rx(" \\+ ");
    boost::algorithm::split_regex( resultArray, expression, rx);
    for (size_t i=0; i<resultArray.size();i++)
    {   
        cout << "[" << i << "] : " << resultArray[i]<< endl ;
    }   
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jdibling@hurricane:~/dev/hacks$ ./hacks 
[0] : A+
[1] : B
```